# fail to publish to Pack-Broker: duplicate key value violation

Tags: pact-jvm, pact-broker

We are now facing a problem when re-publish pacts to the broker when the version and tag remain the same, but the content of the pact is changed between (re)publish trials

Recently our CICD started using a completely new pact broker server, that replaces the old one.
Old broker image was from dius/pact-broker
New broker image is from pactfoundation/pact-broker (latest)

To publish pacts, we are using the "pact:publish" maven plugin command

The scenario:
(The values of projectVersion and tag are the same between trials)

1. When publish pact for the 1st time, everything works fine (return 201)
2. When re-publish, while pact content remain the same, return ok (200), as nothing was changed in the pact
3. When re-publish, but pact content was changes, return error 500, says one or more of the pact files was rejected by the broker.

on the pact broker log, the error shows as follows:

2019-09-18 08:38:50.512340 E [9:puma 001 delegate.rb:83] root -- PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unq_latest_ppid_prov_conver"
DETAIL:  Key (provider_id, consumer_version_id)=(15, 39) already exists.: INSERT INTO "latest_pact_publication_ids_for_consumer_versions" ("consumer_version_id", "provider_id", "pact_publication_id", "consumer_id", "pact_version_id") VALUES (39, 15, 71, 16, 48) RETURNING NULL
2019-09-18 08:38:50.513334 E [9:puma 001 logging.rb:37] root -- Error reference YouFegbNWY - Sequel::UniqueConstraintViolation PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unq_latest_ppid_prov_conver"
DETAIL:  Key (provider_id, consumer_version_id)=(15, 39) already exists.

I would expect that pact broker would allow me to replace, for the same version and tag, the existing pact content, with the new one (as far as I can say - that worked fine in the "old" pact broker)

Answer (score 1):

Issue was with wrong Postgress DB version.